# Experience vs experiences

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

In learners dictionary, [*experience*](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/experience) can be **countable** with the meaning of

> something that you have done

and **uncountable** with the meaning of

> skill or knowledge you get by doing.

Then, what is correct expression

> 1. ...  with decades of experiences in software and hardware design ...

or

> 2. ...  with decades of experience in software and hardware design ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the usual expression is

> ... with decades of **experience** in software and hardware design ...

if you are (for example) writing a resume. This is because, collectively,  your work and studies regarding these matters constitute your *skill or knowledge* about them.

However, it might be possible to say

> ... with decades of experience**s** in software and hardware design ...

but this sounds like you are talking about all the instances where you dealt with software and hardware design. In other words, it sounds like you are saying that you have decades worth of **stories** regarding software and hardware design. I doubt this is what you mean.

Comment: Good point about the potential meaning of the plural.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is at the bottom of the definition you linked:

> b : the length of time that you have spent doing something (such as a particular job)
>
> She has five years' experience as a computer programmer.